# Variable in Array Variable

Tags: vb.net, arrays

if i generate a label dynamically i can change the text as followed, variable is a string:

```
Form.Controls(variable).text = "test"
```

I now have a sub that will create some and will get some information out of arrays. I have a lot of them. I only want the function for tat specific array. I do not want a case or if. Thats why i was wondering if i can use a variable in the array variable. Sounds strange, here is what i mean:

```
Public TestArray() as String

Public Sub BuildStructure(ByVal Shelf As String)    
    Dim XMax as Integer
    XMax = TestArray.GetLength(1)
End Sub
```

But instead of TestArray beeing hardcoded i want it to be replaced with Shelf. So whatever gets send into the sub will change the array that i'm using.

Is that possible some how or is the way totally wrong?

Thanks

Comment: It is not clear at all what your _intent_ is. `Shelf` is a value and `TestArray` is an array. Do you want to make an array with one value, or you want to assign `Shelf` into the array, or something else??? Are all those arrays fields in the same class?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use an `arraylist` object that you can easily add and remove items from at runtime. Here's the MSDN page: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/7x4b0a97.aspx

```
Public TestArray As New ArrayList

Public Sub BuildStructure(ByVal Shelf As String)        
    TestArray.Add(Shelf)
End Sub
```

If you need an array, you can always call the [.ToArray](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.collections.arraylist.toarray.aspx) method on the ArrayList